# Python Dictionary with Keys as Frequencies and Values as Letters

Tags: python

If I have a word like "hello", I want the program to generate a dictionary with the keys being the number of occurrences of the letters and values being a list of the letters.
So "hello" would generate `{1: ['h', 'e', 'o'], 2: ["l"]}`.

Comment: You say "invert a dictionary". Do you *have* a dictionary to invert?

Comment: Actually, I think it should be `2: ["l"]` (a list with one element)?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, it should be like this. I fixed the description.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def occurrences(s):
    h = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in Counter(s).items():
        h[v].append(k)
    return h

occurrences("hello")
```

Output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['h', 'e', 'o'], 2: ['l']})
```

---

A `Counter` is a dictionary that is automatically initialized to zero: with `c = Counter()` you can do `c[key] += 1` even if `key` isn't already in `c`. An additional benefit is that if you pass a list-like object, it builds at once a dictionary with counts. A string is interpreted as a list of characters.

Thus, `Counter("hello")` is the dictionary `Counter({'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 1})`

It's this dictionary you are trying to "reverse".

Now, you just need to create a dictionary of lists, and to append the letters, where the key is the value in the preceding `Counter`.

There is another dictionary class, more or less like `Counter`: `defaultdict`. It allows to decide what will be the initial value. For instance, a `defaultdict(list)` has initial value `[]` (or equivalently, `list()`). So with `h = defaultdict(list)`, you can do `h[1].append("e")` even if `1` is not already a key of `h`.

Note that both `Counter` and `defaultdict` are a subclass of `dict`.

See also the documentation of the [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module.

Comment: only code won't help, so while answering plz add some explain about what ur code is doing

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You need to create a dictionary with count as key and list as values. So you can use defaultdict.

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
inverted = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in Counter(s).items():
    inverted[v].append(k)
return inverted
```

The code block creates a special dictionary. In this dictionary, if you want to access a key never defined, the value will be an empty list. So you can append any values without initiating it. Counter helps you to count every characters in given string. For "hello", the output of `Counter(s).items()` is `dict_items([('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 2), ('o', 1)])` so we need to change key, value pair as you asked. For more information: [collection library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)